# Data is not being read directly from the database instead of buffer on 2nd call

Tags: django, concurrency

I have the following piece of code in my model that ensures that user will be not able to modify a record that was modified by someone else after he has opened it.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        on_disk = Lease.objects.get(pk=self.id)
        self.full_clean()
        if on_disk.version == self.version:
            error = 0 #do nothing
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Record have been modified by another user, please reopen and edit again')
        # self.version = self.version + 1 
        return super(Lease, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There is mechanism implemented(Django concurrency package) that ensures that after each save version value will be modified.

However, this piece of code doesn't work it appears to me that on_disk value is not being populated with the most recent value from the disc but get it from some buffer and as result this code check is useless.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What "buffer" are you talking about here?

Comment: I dont know really. I suspect that this  Lease.objects.get(pk=self.id) query instead of accessing database gets value from some buffer. I do test by having 2 browsers open  and same record in edit mode. I modify one record and save . I expect that when I modify same record in my 2nd open session it will not allow me to save since now my version value is diffrent but for some reason it brings me the same value from DB. So my assumption it is not going to db but reads it from some buffer.

Comment: No. That is not what happens. Potentially though your database itself is locking the item in another transaction, and your transaction isolation setting is preventing this process from seeing an updated value.

Comment: Ok. But I am not getting any error or anything from this locking.
So what can I do? I have my edit form with save and I just try to implement optimistic concurrency somehow.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. That means there is no way to implement optimistic concurrency? I use SQL lite locally and Postgres on Heroku. It behaves the same on both DB's.