# Concurrency protection is not working

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, concurrency

I go bananas here. With my attempts to implement concurrency protection.

So I figured out there are 2 ways to do it.
Optimistic - basically we add a version field to the record and each save will increase it. So if my current version field is different that one on the disc it means something got modified and I give an error.

And the pessimistic approach that means we just lock a record and it will be not possible to edit.

I implemented both ways plus concurrency package for Django and nothing works I teas on SQLLite and on Postgres with Heroku.

Below is my view method it has both approaches

for pessimistic, I lock with transaction atomic using  select_for_update
and for optimistic I use concurrency django package that increases my version field on each edit and do a simple comparison with on_disc value

What I do wrong? Please help?

```
@login_required
    def lease_edit(request,pk,uri):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        title = 'Edit Lease'
        uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)


        with transaction.atomic():

            post = get_object_or_404(Lease.objects.select_for_update(), pk=pk)

            if request.method == "POST":
                form = LeaseForm(request.POST, instance=post)
                if form.is_valid():
                    lease = form.save(commit=False)
                    on_disc= Lease.objects.get(pk=post.id)
                    if on_disc.version > post.version:
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, str(lease.id) + "-Error object was modified by another user. Please reopen object.")
                        return redirect(uri)


                    lease.save()
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(lease.id) + "--SUCCESS Object saved successfully")
                    return redirect(uri)
            else:
                form = LeaseForm(instance=post)
            #lease = post.lease 
            return render(request, 'object_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title':title, 'extend': EXTEND})
```

To test I just open 2 browsers with the same record and try to edit both in parallel (I use same user)

Comment: The code isn't running on the server while you do the edits so the transaction won't be there waiting for you to edit anything. It's only active while you update so naturally there will be no errors between locking, updating and releasing the lock unless you're very very lucky and get two requests running at the exact same time. As for the on disc version number check not working can't say exactly why. Does the code get the ID from the browser or read from database on POST as I seem to see it doing?

Comment: For the optimistic,  I received a comment on another question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692858/data-is-not-being-read-directly-from-the-database-instead-of-buffer-on-2nd-call
"Potentially though your database itself is locking the item in another transaction, and your transaction isolation setting is preventing this process from seeing an updated value. " but I have no clue how to deal with it.

Comment: But do I read the code correctly: you get the `post` from database with select for update, then save, then get `on_disc` and compare? Because neither of those is from the *previous* request, which has the *previous* value. Both these are from *this* request and will always match. You have to send the value to the browser and get it back and compare that value to current one.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen And for the pessimistic when I edit it should get locked.
Since I trigger the select_for_update  before actually loading the form.At least this is what I assume

Comment: No, you trigger it on the update request. This whole code runs at the same time and ends. The transaction doesn't hang around while you edit the data. There is nothing making it wait for you. It locks, loads, unlocks. Then you edit, post data and it again locks, updates, unlocks. It doesn't stop multiple requests from doing whatever they want.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen good point,  I assume  I compare before I save. since it is commit =false. But let me try and do it before it. I am not sure how it behaves because of this commit = false

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen I checked so even if I put my version validation before the lease = form.save(commit=False) its still saves and overweight changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how websites work. Currently your locking works like this:

- GET request loads data

  - you lock the row, load, send to browser, unlock
- you edit data on the browser
- POST data to server

  - you lock the row, update, unlock

There is nothing here that keeps the row locked. Multiple instances can send data to the server since the row is unlocked after each request. This is the way web systems usually work, each request is separate and locking has to be done differently.

As for the row versioning, if I understand the code correctly you don't send the current row number to the browser but you read it while updating. This again means that you get the correct number. You should send the current number to the browser and on POST compare that number to the current number in the database. This way if something changes it detects it.

I may be wrong about this part since I'm not familiar with Django but this is my understanding of the functionality of the code. I would assume `form` might have the current row version but it's not compared to anything, only the current number in database and one after update (which also might change the number possibly).

Comment: I didn't make it work yet. Since I have an issue getting the version  from the form. But I guess you are correct. thank you